# how to show checkbox checked in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

hi I am working on multiple checkbox and  the value of checkboxes is storing in this format in my database 2,3,4
code of my blade file:-

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        @foreach($var as $vars)

                     <tbody>
                      <tr>
                       <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]"  value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 1 ? 'checked' : '')}}>Cold/Hot Forging
                       </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 2 ? 'checked' : '')}}>Injection Molding
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 3 ? 'checked' : '')}}>Precision Machining
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 4 ? 'checked' : '')}}>Sheet Metal Pressing
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 5 ? 'checked' : '')}}>Sub-assembly
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 6 ? 'checked' : '')}}>Surface tretment
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value=""  {{ ($vars->process == 7 ? 'checked' : '')}}> Other
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  @endforeach
               </table>
```

so this code is showing me only one checkbox checked whose value is 2
controller code:-

```
$processvalue = ProcessValue::where('company_basic_info_id','=',$id)->get();
```

Comment: You're storing a comma separated string of values (`2,3,4`)?

Comment: This will never be true `$vars->process == 1` if `$vars->process = '1,2,3'`.

Answer (score 2):

To make this happen,

First convert database value in array,

```
$var = '2,3,4';   // Your checkbox values in database
$allCheckboxValues = explode(",",$var);  // Convert it in array
```

Then put it in your checkboxes,

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]"  value="1"  {{ (in_array(1,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}>Cold/Hot Forging
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value="2"  {{ (in_array(2,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}>Injection Molding
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value="3"  {{ (in_array(3,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}>Precision Machining
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value="4"  {{ (in_array(4,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}>Sheet Metal Pressing
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value="5"  {{ (in_array(5,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}>Sub-assembly
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value="6"  {{ (in_array(6,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}>Surface tretment
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="larger" name="process[]" value="7"  {{ (in_array(7,$allCheckboxValues) ? 'checked' : '')}}> Other
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you make an array with all data

```
<?php 
$all_processvalue = array();
foreach($processvalue as $pvalue){
     $all_data[] =  $pvalue->id;
}
?>
```

Now you create checkbox

```
@foreach ($vars as $var)
    {{ Form::checkbox('var[]', $var->id, in_array($var->id, $all_processvalue )) }}
    {{ Form::label('var', $var->name) }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Wait let me check